# iPhone Call Forwarding to Contacts

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have an iPhone provided by my employer and I regularly have to set up call forwarding to different numbers. As far as I can see, you always have to type in the number you want to forward to (or copy & paste it), but you can't simply select one of your contacts. Is there some reason for this I am not aware of? Is there some trick to speed up this process (other than adding the contacts to your favorites and copying the numbers from there)? Is there an app which makes this process more user-friendly?

Comment: How are you forwarding the call?  If you're doing it through carrier function codes, it's not like the carrier's infrastructure has access to the Contacts app on the phone.

Comment: I'm entering the number under `Settings -> Phone -> Call Forwarding`, and the Settings could very well have an option to select a number from your contacts?

Comment: Huh.  Don't have that selection on my phone.  It appears in the search results in Settings but there is no such option.  iP12Pro/Verizon.  When I've wanted to do this, I've used *71/*72/*73 for conditional and always and off.